# Convert string as key => value pairs

Tags: php, string

I have the followed string:

```
Host                          dnsmgr   Username       Refresh State                Reg.Time
sip.voicetrading.com:5060     N        travelAsk        105 Registered           Thu, 27 Nov 2014 15:57:43
sip.alonia.es:5060            N        user431          225 Registered           Thu, 27 Nov 2014 23:28:24
```

I want to somehow make this string as associative array.

Something like this:

```
array(
   'sip.voicetrading.com' => array (
       'port'   => 5060,
       'username' =>'travelAsk',
       'refresh'   => 105,
       'state'     => 'Registered',
       'time'      => 'Thu, 27 Nov 2014 15:57:43'
   ),
   'sip.alonia.es' => array (
       'port'   => 5060,
       'username' =>' user431',
       'refresh'   => 225,
       'state'     => 'Registered',
       'time'      => 'Thu, 27 Nov 2014 23:28:24'
   )
);
```

Can you suggest me a way how it would be the best way to do it.

So far I tried something like this:

```
$peer = array(
  "data"=>
"Host                                    dnsmgr Username       Refresh State                Reg.Time                 
sip.voicetrading.com:5060               N      travelIhome        105 Registered           Thu, 27 Nov 2014 16:39:45 " ;


foreach (explode("\n", $peer['data']) as $line) {

    $a = strpos('z' . $line, ':') - 1;
    if ($a >= 0) {
        $arrTrunkSettings = explode (' ', trim(substr($line, $a + 1)));
        foreach ($arrTrunkSettings as $key => $value) {
            if (!empty($value)) {
                $data[trim(substr($line, 0, $a))][] = $value;   
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and the Output is like this array with numeric indexes:
But this actually is not what I need.

```
array (
  "sip.voicetrading.com" =>
  array(
    [0]=> "5060"
    [1]=> "N"
    [2]=> "travelAsk"
    [3]=> "105"
    [4]=> "Registered"
    [5]=> "Thu,"
    [6]=> "27"
    [7]=> "Nov"
    [8]=> "2014"
    [9]=> "16:32:45"
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Shorted the solution quite a bit. This does the same as my first answer, but now in half the code. First it gets all lines, then pulls and splits the headers into a seperate array. Then it can loop the rest of the lines and add them into the result using the headers as keys.

```
$result = array();

$lines = explode("\n", $string);
$headers = preg_split("/\s+/", array_shift($lines), 6);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $part = preg_split('/\s+/', $line, 6);
    $info = explode(":", $part[0]);
    $result[$info[0]]['port'] = $info[1];
    for($i = 1; $i < count($headers); $i++) {
        $result[$info[0]][$headers[$i]] = $part[$i];
    }    
}
```

This gives you a result array matching what you asked for. It's gets the keys/value pairs from the headers, so if the input changes, so does the resulting array, unlike the hardcoded solution.

Answer (score 0):

- You should indeed split the input for new lines
- You should eliminate unnecessary white space
- Then you should split every row for one space and store the values in necessary columns in your associative array

This is the implementation:

```
<?php
$input = "Host                          dnsmgr   Username       Refresh State                Reg.Time
sip.voicetrading.com:5060     N        travelAsk        105 Registered           Thu, 27 Nov 2014 15:57:43
sip.alonia.es:5060            N        user431          225 Registered           Thu, 27 Nov 2014 23:28:24";

$rows = explode("\n", $input);
unset($rows[0]);
$objects = array();
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $object = array();
    echo $row . "\n";
    $row = preg_replace("/\\ +/", " ", $row); //Reducing all whitespace into single spaces

    $index = strpos($row, " ");
    $addr = substr($row, 0, $index);
    $host = substr($addr, 0, strpos($addr, ":"));
    $port = str_replace($host.":", "", $addr);
    $row = substr($row, $index + 1, strlen($row));

    $index = strpos($row, " ");
    $mgr = substr($row, 0, $index);
    $row = substr($row, $index + 1, strlen($row));

    $index = strpos($row, " ");
    $user = substr($row, 0, $index);
    $row = substr($row, $index + 1, strlen($row));

    $index = strpos($row, " ");
    $refresh = substr($row, 0, $index);
    $row = substr($row, $index + 1, strlen($row));

    $index = strpos($row, " ");
    $state = substr($row, 0, $index);
    $row = substr($row, $index + 1, strlen($row));

    $object["port"] = $port;
    $object["dnsmgr"] = $mgr;
    $object["username"] = $user;
    $object["refresh"] = $refresh;
    $object["state"] = $state;
    $object["time"] = $row;

    $objects[$host] = $object;
}

print_r($objects);
?>
```

Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably save yourself quite a lot of trouble by just using `preg_split()`:

```
<?php

$peer = array( "data" =>
"Host                          dnsmgr   Username       Refresh State                Reg.Time
sip.voicetrading.com:5060     N        travelAsk        105 Registered           Thu, 27 Nov 2014 15:57:43
sip.alonia.es:5060            N        user431          225 Registered           Thu, 27 Nov 2014 23:28:24"
); 

$obj = array();

foreach( explode( "\n", $peer['data'] ) as $line ) {
  $v1 = preg_split( "/:/", trim( $line ), 2 );
  if( sizeof( $v1 ) == 2 ) {
    $v2 = preg_split( "/\s+/", $v1[1], 6 );
    $obj[$v1[0]] = array(
      "port"     => $v2[0],
      "username" => $v2[2],
      "refresh"  => $v2[3],
      "state"    => $v2[4],
      "time"     => $v2[5]
    );
  }
}

print_r( $obj );

?>
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [sip.voicetrading.com] => Array
        (
            [port] => 5060
            [username] => travelAsk
            [refresh] => 105
            [state] => Registered
            [time] => Thu, 27 Nov 2014 15:57:43
        )

    [sip.alonia.es] => Array
        (
            [port] => 5060
            [username] => user431
            [refresh] => 225
            [state] => Registered
            [time] => Thu, 27 Nov 2014 23:28:24
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
<?php

  $peer = array('data' =>
'Host                          dnsmgr   Username       Refresh State                Reg.Time
sip.voicetrading.com:5060     N        travelAsk        105 Registered           Thu, 27 Nov 2014 15:57:43
sip.alonia.es:5060            N        user431          225 Registered           Thu, 27 Nov 2014 23:28:24'
  );
```

First, split the raw data into lines. Extract the field labels from the first row, and delete this row. Replace the first label with `"Port"`.

```
  $lines = explode ("\n", $peer['data']);
  if (count ($lines)) {
    $line = array_shift ($lines);
    $labels = preg_split ('/\\s+/', trim($line));
    $labels[0] = 'Port';
    $max_fields = count ($labels);
  }
```

Now loop over the remaining lines. Split the lines into fields, and extract the host and port from the first field. Replace the first field with the port. Then use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to merge the labels and data.

Note the use of `$max_fields` to avoid splitting the `Reg.Time` into several fields. This only works if `Reg.Time` is the last field in the row.

```
  $data = array();
  foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $fields = preg_split ('/\\s+/', trim($line), $max_fields);
    if (count ($fields) < $max_fields) {
      // Error
    }
    $hostport = explode (':', $fields[0], 2);
    $host = $hostport[0];
    $port = $hostport[1];
    $fields[0] = $port;
    $data[$host] = array_combine ($labels, $fields);
  }

  print_r ($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to parse this data. I felt like the easiest way was to just write a regexp for it.

```
$peerData = 'Host                          dnsmgr   Username       Refresh State                Reg.Time
         sip.voicetrading.com:5060     N        travelAsk        105 Registered           Thu, 27 Nov 2014 15:57:43
         sip.alonia.es:5060            N        user431          225 Registered           Thu, 27 Nov 2014 23:28:24';

// Split the string into lines
$lines = explode("\n", $peerData);

// Remove the header
unset($lines[0]);

// Loop over each line
$peers = [];
foreach ($lines as $line) {

    $matches = [];
    preg_match('/\s*(?P<hostname>[\w\.]+):(?P<port>\d+)\s*(?P<dnsmgr>.)\s*(?P<username>\w+)\s*(?P<refresh>\d+)\s*(?P<state>\w+)\s*(?P<time>.+)/', $line, $matches);

    // Build the entry
    $peers[$matches['hostname']] = [
        'port'     => $matches['port'],
        'username' => $matches['username'],
        'refresh'  => $matches['refresh'],
        'state'    => $matches['state'],
        'time'     => $matches['time'],
    ];
}

print_r($peers);
```

[Regex explanation](http://regex101.com/r/aJ0jJ8/1)

### Result

```
Array
(
    [sip.voicetrading.com] => Array
        (
            [port] => 5060
            [username] => travelAsk
            [refresh] => 105
            [state] => Registered
            [time] => Thu, 27 Nov 2014 15:57:43
        )

    [sip.alonia.es] => Array
        (
            [port] => 5060
            [username] => user431
            [refresh] => 225
            [state] => Registered
            [time] => Thu, 27 Nov 2014 23:28:24
        )
)
```